# Bluetooth keeps disconnecting after being connected to another Android device for a while

Tags: android, bluetooth

I have an Xperia Z3C, Android 5.1.1 and I'm trying to connect it to a Nexus 4 Android 6.0.1 via Bluetooth. Pairing them is OK, but when I try to connect them, it says 'Connected' for less than a second and automatically disconnects.

Is this a known issue? I haven't found anything about this.

Here's what logcat says:

```
03-14 17:25:55.308: E/bt-btif(14245): bte_scan_filt_param_cfg_evt, 1
03-14 17:25:55.308: E/bt-btif(14245): bte_scan_filt_param_cfg_evt, 1
03-14 17:25:55.990: E/bt-btm(14245): new address: xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx
03-14 17:25:55.990: E/bt-btm(14245): new address: xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx
03-14 17:25:56.712: E/bt-btm(14245): new address: xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx
03-14 17:25:57.464: E/bt-btif(14245): bte_scan_filt_param_cfg_evt, 1
03-14 17:25:57.814: E/bt-btm(14245): Ignoring RNR as the state is not BTM_SEC_STATE_GETTING_NAME
03-14 17:25:57.933: E/NetlinkEvent(318): Unknown ifindex 41 in RTM_DELADDR
03-14 17:25:57.963: E/dhcpcd(15974): bt-pan: interface not found or invalid
03-14 17:25:57.986: E/BluetoothPanServiceJni(14245): ## ERROR : disconnectPanNative(L224): Failed disconnect pan channel, status: 1##
03-14 17:25:58.139: E/BluetoothTetheringNetworkFactory(14245): DHCP request error:DHCP result was failed
03-14 17:26:01.382: E/bt-btm(14245): btm_sec_disconnected - Clearing Pending flag
```

Comment: There's a pretty lengthy and varied bug regarding bluetooth problems and Android 5.x.   It gets a lot of people reporting on things but not a lot of useful information regarding what's wrong with it.   

https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=79488

Comment: I posted all the information I had, I cant' find out what is happening. I was developing a Bluetooth Printing application and was trying to test it with an application that emulates a BT printer on the Nexus. I didn't even try to send data to it because bluetooth connection was failing, but, when I did after asking this question, data was sent successful, although the two devices weren't connected. I have no idea what's going on here. @RobertNekic

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem while trying to scan for Bluetooth devices from my Android application. The interesting thing is that it does not throw any exception (caught or uncaught) and fails silently! The problem occurs for devices with API Level >= 23 (Android 6.0). Here is an extract of my Logcat logs :

```
03-30 14:07:52.099 192-211/? I/BufferQueueProducer: [org.manios.testbt/org.manios.testbt.printing.BluetoothPrinterDiscovery](this:0x7fa16de400,id:1467,api:1,p:26262,c:192) queueBuffer: fps=0.19 dur=5154.29 max=5154.29 min=5154.29
03-30 14:07:52.114 192-192/? I/SurfaceFlinger: [Built-in Screen (type:0)] fps:1.091767,dur:1831.89,max:999.66,min:832.23
03-30 14:07:52.137 774-1001/? D/InputReader: AP_PROF:AppLaunch_dispatchPtr:Up:89556864, ID:0, Index:2056797440
03-30 14:07:52.137 774-1001/? I/PerfService: PerfServiceNative_boostEnableTimeoutMsAsync:3, 100
03-30 14:07:52.138 26262-26262/org.manios.testbt D/SettingsInterface:  from settings cache , name = sound_effects_enabled , value = 0
03-30 14:07:52.138 26262-26262/org.manios.testbt D/BluetoothAdapter: isEnabled
03-30 14:07:52.140 26262-26262/org.manios.testbt D/BluetoothAdapter: getName
03-30 14:07:52.141 774-1636/? D/BluetoothManagerService: checkIfCallerIsForegroundUser: valid=true callingUser=0 parentUser=-10000 foregroundUser=0
03-30 14:07:52.142 21807-21818/? D/BluetoothAdapterProperties: getName: mName = Lenovo TAB3 8
03-30 14:07:52.144 26262-666/org.manios.testbt D/BluetoothAdapter: isEnabled
03-30 14:07:52.146 26262-666/org.manios.testbt D/BluetoothAdapter: isDiscovering
03-30 14:07:52.148 26262-666/org.manios.testbt D/BluetoothAdapter: 109507751: getState(). Returning 12
03-30 14:07:52.152 21807-21817/? D/BluetoothAdapterProperties: isDiscovering: mDiscovering = false
03-30 14:07:52.156 26262-666/org.manios.testbt D/BluetoothAdapter: startDiscovery
03-30 14:07:52.158 26262-666/org.manios.testbt D/BluetoothAdapter: 109507751: getState(). Returning 12
03-30 14:07:52.160 21807-21830/? W/bt_btif: bta_dm_check_av:0
03-30 14:07:52.172 21807-21830/? E/bt_btif: bte_scan_filt_param_cfg_evt, 1
03-30 14:07:52.181 21807-21823/? I/BluetoothAdapterProperties: Callback:discoveryStateChangeCallback with state:1
03-30 14:07:52.182 774-2924/? V/ActivityManager: Broadcast: Intent { act=android.bluetooth.adapter.action.DISCOVERY_STARTED flg=0x10 } ordered=false userid=0 callerApp=ProcessRecord{c376192 21807:com.android.bluetooth/1002}
03-30 14:07:52.184 1057-1265/? V/BluetoothEventManager: Received android.bluetooth.adapter.action.DISCOVERY_STARTED
03-30 14:07:52.185 1057-1265/? D/BluetoothEventManager: scanning state change to true
03-30 14:07:52.186 21983-21983/? D/ActivityThread: BDC-Calling onReceive: intent=Intent { act=android.bluetooth.adapter.action.DISCOVERY_STARTED flg=0x10 cmp=com.android.settings/.bluetooth.BluetoothDiscoveryReceiver }, receiver=com.android.settings.bluetooth.BluetoothDiscoveryReceiver@b02fe63
03-30 14:07:52.186 21983-21983/? V/BluetoothDiscoveryReceiver: Received: android.bluetooth.adapter.action.DISCOVERY_STARTED
03-30 14:07:52.187 21983-21983/? D/ActivityThread: BDC-RECEIVER handled : 0 / ReceiverData{intent=Intent { act=android.bluetooth.adapter.action.DISCOVERY_STARTED flg=0x10 cmp=com.android.settings/.bluetooth.BluetoothDiscoveryReceiver } packageName=com.android.settings resultCode=-1 resultData=null resultExtras=null}
03-30 14:07:52.218 774-1001/? D/InputReader: AP_PROF:AppLaunch_dispatchPtr:Down:89556946, ID:0, Index:2056794048
03-30 14:07:52.219 774-1001/? I/PerfService: PerfServiceNative_boostEnableAsync:3
```

I found after some searching using this [issue](https://github.com/don/BluetoothSerial/issues/194), that in API Level >= 23 (Android 6.0) we have to add the following permission to AndroidManifext.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
```

so that scanning and other Bluetooth actions function properly.

In Android documentation it states in [BluetoothAdapter.startDiscovery()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothAdapter.html#startDiscovery()) that it requires [BLUETOOTH_ADMIN](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#BLUETOOTH_ADMIN) permission with no further details. But if we take a look into [BluetoothLeScanner.startScan()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/le/BluetoothLeScanner.html#startScan(java.util.List%3Candroid.bluetooth.le.ScanFilter%3E,%20android.bluetooth.le.ScanSettings,%20android.bluetooth.le.ScanCallback)),it states clearly that:

> Requires [BLUETOOTH_ADMIN](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#BLUETOOTH_ADMIN) permission. An app must hold [ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) or [ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) permission in order to get results.

Hope this helps!

Comment: @IgorGanapolsky I updated my answer with links to the official Android documentation.

Answer (score 1):

So two things can be going on here. Either the second device that you are trying to maintain a connection with is having an issue maintaining a connection or there is an interference being caused between the two just long enough to break the connection but not long enough to terminate it completely.

Comment: What do you mean by interference?

Comment: Bluetooth interference can be caused by a number of things, short list here: https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201542